# Retrieving hardware info for Windows and Linux

Tags: linux, windows, hardware, serial-number

I have a dual boot (Ubuntu and Win7) machine and I need retrieve some hardware info. In this first moment, I'll list the following:

1. Processor ID or Serial Number;
2. Motherboard Serial Number;
3. Hard-disk Serial Number;
4. Graphical card Serial Number.

Is there any way to get those information, with same data, from both OS, using native programs (non-downloaded programs)?

PS: I'm developing in Java, so any command line or other libraries are accepted.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For linux: `grep -R . /sys/class/dmi`

Comment: Also for linux (depending on distro):  /usr/sbin/hwinfo  (this command has options to get just specific info items)

Comment: Executing `grep -R . /sys/class/dmi` I have to use sudo to execute its fully functionality. But for example, some serials come filled by a huge "BLANK" value.

Answer (score 1):

For Windows 7, you can use [WMIC](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb742610.aspx) and [Get-WmiObject](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176860.aspx) in PowerShell to get processor and GPU serials, e.g.,

```
> Get-WmiObject Win32_Processor
> WMIC PATH Win32_VideoController GET Description,PNPDeviceID
```

See also [this thread](https://superuser.com/questions/469216/is-it-possible-to-get-the-serial-number-of-a-gpu-without-opening-the-case).